# Understanding the format('b') option - need a little clarification

Tags: python, binary, format

After reading the Python manual on the format option I am still a little unclear on the binary options.

```
res = ''.join(format(ord(i), 'b') for i in test_str)
```

My understanding is that the above code will output each character of my string to its binary equivalent. If I change `'b'` to `'8b'`, `'08b'` or even `'010b'` my output is different. I'm just not sure what the numbers represent in front of the `b`.

Comment: The [`format` docs](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#format) link to [this](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatspec), did you read it?

Comment: `8b` → make the output at least 8 fields wide, fill up the left side with spaces; `08b` →same, but fill with `0`s.

Comment: Ok this makes sense, the docs were confusing me a little, thank you for the clear explanation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Klaus D's comment has a good explanation of the behavior, but here's a visual. In both cases, the resulting string is at least 8 characters wide, and with the `0`, any leading empty spots in the representation will be padded with zeroes. I'm using f-strings here, but the behavior is the same with `.format`:

```
In [24]: for ex in range(5):
    ...:     print(f'{10**ex:08b}')
    ...: for ex in range(5):
    ...:     print(f'{10**ex:8b}')
    ...:
00000001
00001010
01100100
1111101000
10011100010000
       1
    1010
 1100100
1111101000
10011100010000
```

Comment: Thank you kindly, this really helps to cement this in my mind